# Rails File Upload progress bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I'm trying upload video to Wistia. They have an example for this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/http/post/multipart'

def post_video_to_wistia(name, path_to_video)
  uri = URI('https://upload.wistia.com/')

  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true

  # Construct the request.
  request = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new uri.request_uri, {
  'api_password' => '<API_PASSWORD>',
  'contact_id'   => '<CONTACT_ID>', # Optional.
  'project_id'   => '<PROJECT_ID>', # Optional.
  'name'         => '<MEDIA_NAME>', # Optional.

  'file' => UploadIO.new(
            File.open(path_to_video),
            'application/octet-stream',
            File.basename(path_to_video)
          )
  }

  # Make it so!
  response = http.request(request)

  return response
end
```

All works good. But how I can build progress bar for uploading process using Streaming Response Bodies?

Comment: were u able to figure it out?